# Any implication of a Yale result to security of quantum cryptology?

Tags: quantum-cryptography

Quantum key distribution depends, if I don't err, on (irreversible) damages done by MITM's measurements on qbits. Now news.yale.edu/2013/01/11/new-qubit-control-bodes-well-future-quantum-computing says:

"The Yale physicists successfully devised a new, non-destructive measurement system for observing, tracking and documenting all changes in a qubit’s state, thus preserving the qubit’s informational value."

Wouldn't the new technique, if not immediately practically, at least in long term render the security of QKD questionable?

Comment: The article is pretty vague but I doubt that it intends to say that you can measure arbitrary qubits in a non destructive manner. It sounds like a highly specific form of measurement that allows you detect certain errors in quantum computing.

Answer (score 4):

No.  The [Yale result](http://qulab.eng.yale.edu/documents/papers/Hatridge%20et%20al,%20Quantum%20Back%20Action%20of%20Variable%20Strength%20Measurement.pdf) describes a method of partial measurement that is not completely destructive to the quantum system's coherence, which is tied to its [physical representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit#Physical_representation).  It is not a refutation of [quantum indeterminacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_indeterminacy), which is the basis for (provably secure) quantum key exchange.  In other words, the Yale team measured a qubit in such a way that it doesn't "fall apart" (decohere) when it's measured - in the author's words, "the measurement record faithfully reports the perturbation of the system after the fact." However, the act of measurement still [affects the qubit's information content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit#Operations_on_pure_qubit_states) in accordance with the mathematics of quantum mechanics.

Comment: There is a very recent paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7351 by R. Anderson and R. Brady entitled "Why quantum computing is hard - and quantum cryptography is not provably secure". I should very much appreciate it, if some experts could evaluate that paper.